# C# Call LogonUser fail with SecureString

Tags: c#, security, winapi

everyone, I am facing an issue with `LogonUser` function.

I just want to know if I can import the `LogonUser` function into C# by this signature:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int LogonUser(string username, string domain, IntPtr password, int logonType, int logonProvider, ref IntPtr token);
```

Because I want to secure my password not using a string, but a `SecureString` class. Then later the function is used like below:

```
var passwordPtr = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(password);
var result = LogonUser(userName, domain, passwordPtr, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token);
```

I always get result = 0 and the message shows that the user name and password is incorrect.
But when I change the signature to use string password, then everything works well.

Please help me as to secure the password with `SecureString` is important to me.

Comment: That's how you would do it..  The MSDN page for `SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode` has a complete example for calling `LogonUser`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.securestringtoglobalallocunicode(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: An obvious issue would be if you've got the P/Invoke signature wrong and are trying to pass Unicode text to the Ansi version of `LogonUser` - but I can't say for sure since you've not shown your P/Invoke signature.

Comment: I just updated the signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Alex K, there's an example of using `LogonUser` in the [`SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.securestringtoglobalallocunicode(v=vs.100).aspx). Note that the P/Invoke declaration there is:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern bool LogonUser(String username, String domain, IntPtr password,
            int logonType, int logonProvider, ref IntPtr token);
```

And that `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` has been specified. Unfortunately, for historical reasons, the default [`CharSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b93s42f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value is `Ansi` and so that's what *your* P/Invoke attempt is going to use.

This will be fine for the `username` parameter since the P/Invoke infrastructure will ensure that it converts the `string` appropriately. But it's not appropriate for the `password` parameter since *you've* already performed the string conversion and you've done it as Unicode - and all that P/Invoke is seeing is an `IntPtr` now.

I'd suggest updating your P/Invoke signature to match that given in the sample.

---

Another alternative would be to switch to using [`SecureStringToGlobalAllocAnsi`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.securestringtoglobalallocansi(v=vs.100).aspx) and leaving your P/Invoke signature alone. But this is a seriously second-rate solution. Writing non-Unicode aware code in 2015 is seriously not to be recommended.

Just get in the habit of *always* specifying `CharSet.Unicode` in any P/Invoke signatures you write.

Comment: Thanks Damien_The_Unbeliever and Alex K. I tried to update the signature with charset to Unicode, and it is working fine now. I just didn't realize this settings, and compared many times of the function signature in the article Alex K mentioned:)